# Quartz Scheduler Cron Expression with frequency as specific hour and minute

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to build a cron expression using quartz in java. I get two parameters as hour and minute with which I have to schedule a job every hour and minute.
Till now I have tried this :
**Example 1:-**
**Schedule job to run every 1 hour 10 minutes.**
- I used cron expression for this example as "0 */10 */1 * * ?".
- But this job runs every 10th minute and not as 1 hour and 10 minutes.

Can anyone help me understand why this expression is not working ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cron expression will run every 10 minutes because that's what the first `*/10` means. The second `*/1` is redundant because it'll run anyway due to the first `*/10`.

It's not clear to me what you're trying to do - recurring schedules can be tricky to express clearly, so I tend to write down a few examples and work from there.

Are you trying to get a pattern like:

1. 01:10
2. 02:10
3. 03:10

If so, I think `0 10 * * * ?` should do the job. The documentation I used to understand the expression is at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html and I also found http://www.cronmaker.com/ to be really helpful for sanity checking the expression - it'll work out the next few trigger times for you.

To achieve firing at a fixed rate every 1:10, i.e.

1. 1:10
2. 2:20
3. 3:30

try the [SimpleTrigger](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html) with a 1:10 interval.

Comment: Hello Brabster,
I tried the above cron expression and it worked fine for the pattern you mentioned. 
But I want to get a pattern like :

1. 01:10
2. 02:20
3. 03:30

Comment: I'm not sure you can express that with a single cron expression - it's really triggering with a fixed interval of 1:10. You could do it with a few expressions, one for the ten-past the hour triggers, another for the 20-past the hour, etc. if it's important to use cron for some reason. A different kind of trigger might be better if you want something simple and easy to understand - SimpleTrigger supports triggering with a simple interval, for example http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html

Comment: @Aniruddha I've updated my answer to include SimpleTrigger advice - an upvote (because helpful) and accept (because solved the problem) on my answer is how we do things on StackOverflow :)

Comment: I did an upvote for your answer which is accepted internally. The upvote will be visible only if I have a reputation above or equal to 15. Thank you again for the help. :)